# how mongodb operates with documents during the query

Tags: mongodb, query-optimization, database

That's quite a specific questions.

Let's assume - we have a collection's of large documents, each of them have a large ammount of data, and we don't have additional indexes.

So, when I query like something like this `{field_name: "test_value"}` Is it just look from all document from top to bottom, trying to find necessary field and then check it's value (like a full text search), or maybe it have some optimization like store documents with some metadata, or order fields in document in alphabet order or maybe some else internal documents optimizations??? (Like hashtables, some index, etc)

Because if we have a 16mb of raw text data, lust looking through all document trying to find necessary key - that's could be time consuming.

Comment: If you don't have indexes, that's a fullscan. You want faster queries - index the data.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's all so simple. Think some optimization still exist. For example - I try to save just test document, and then print it. And in result doc some fields have a bit different order.

Comment: You're welcome to peruse mongodb source code. :)

Comment: That's a good solution and one day I'll definitely will look through the key parts. So, the main problem for me it's not read it, but find which part of the code responsible for.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any indexes (except of _id which you always have) - this is a full scan with no optimization (the optimization as you called it hashtables, some index, some metadata are actually indexes which are created to speed up your query). May be 16 Mb will not be as time-consuming as you think, but without index it will go through all documents (except of when you are doing findOne or limit and you got lucky and get those 1 or few elements in the beginning) one by one and try to match a pattern.

Because people where not satisfied with this O(n) speed they came up with idea of indexes.